# How to get current month name and year in SAS using macro

Tags: sql, sas

I am triggering a mail in SAS which should holds current month and year in the mail

How can I create macro variables `&month` `&year`such that

- `&month` should display October
- `&year`  should display 2020

Currently using

```
%let sysmonth= %sysfunc(month("&sysdate"d));
%let sysyear= %sysfunc(year("&sysdate"d));

%put &sysmonth &sysyear;
```

But I am getting month in number but i want the month in words

Comment: Please edit the question to share the code you are using to create the email, as you might not need macro variables for the month and year, as this can be achievable through data step code.

Answer (score 3):

Use `PUTN` with format `MONNAME`

```
%put %sysfunc(PUTN("&sysdate"d, monname.));
------ LOG ------
October
```

Comment: Richard how should I change it to get last month of current month that is if iam running in october it should show september how can i do that?

Comment: `%sysfunc()` has a second parameter that allows you specify the format. Use the `intnx()` function to get the prior month. `%let prior_month =  %sysfunc(intnx(month, "&sysdate."d, -1, b), monname.);`

Answer (score 3):

`%SYSFUNC` has an optional second argument that specifies format.  In the particular case here you don't really need it - Richard's PUTN works just as well - but in the case that you do want a function to operate, here's that example - the example here being for if you want a different month than the current one, but any function works this way.

```
%let sysmonth= %sysfunc(intnx(month,"&sysdate"d,-1),monname.);
%put &=sysmonth;
```