# SAS global variable for date

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I want to create a sas macro global variable with current month in the format OCT i.e., only first 3 letters of current month are expected in the output in upper case. Please guide me.

Comment: Show what you tried so far, even if it did not work.

Comment: I think the easiest to do this would be to do this within a data step. I would change the number into a date in the date9. format (e.g. 01OCT2020), then change the date to string and then take the middle 3 characters

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64419876/i-want-to-extract-month-data-from-a-datetime-format-column-in-sas

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64351082/how-to-get-current-month-name-and-year-in-sas-using-macro

Comment: This is a homework question somewhere I assume? The two responses above are from the past week and the latter one has the exact answer you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
220  %let cm3 = %sysfunc(putn("&sysdate"d,monname,3),$upcase3.);
221  %put NOTE: &=cm3;
NOTE: CM3=OCT
```